# What does it mean by "I'm up front" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The oldest boy came striding into sight. He had already changed into his billowing black Hogwarts robes, and Harry noticed a shiny red and gold badge on his chest with the letter P on it.
>
> "Can't stay long, mother. **I'm up front**, the prefects have got two compartments to themselves.."

It's from Harry potter and they are now at platform nine and three quaters.

I understood Percy's "I'm up front" as "being in a conspicuous or leading position" as in the definition I looked up in the [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up-front) dictionary,

but in the translated version of this book in my language, it's translated literally like "I'm over there(I am in the front compartment or just somewhere up front). The prefects occupied two compartments..." which I think is weird also in my language.

Which one is correct? Is it mistranslation?

Comment: The oldest boy has a badge with the letter "P" on it. He is in a hurry because he needs to get to the front of the train where the two compartments for the **P**refects are...

Comment: Thanks but can I ask you one more? You said "the front of the train where the two compartments for the Prefects are". Does this sentence mean there were two compartments (which is on the front) prepared only for the prefects? Just that? But as I mentioned, in the translated version in my language, it is written like "The prefects occupied(or possessed?) two compartments" rather than "there are 2 compartments up front prepared for the prefects". That translation can also be right?

Comment: "The Prefects have got two compartments to themselves" is a way of saying that two compartments have been set aside only for prefects, and  only the prefects can use them. Because they don't have to share, you could argue that they possess them (at least until the train ride is over). Another example, "The kids are away at school, so we have the whole house to ourselves until winter break." We still own our house whether or not the kids are home, but we don't have to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percy is saying he will be riding in the front compartments of the train. To ride 'up front' means to ride in the front part of a vehicle.

Comment: Thanks but how do I know that if 'up front' here means what you had answered or what I guessed at first? I can only guess through the context? Did this confusion occur because I'm not used to this expression?

Comment: And why isn't it "I need or I have to go to the front", but just "I'm up front" ? It seems like he is now in the front of the compartment but he's talking to his mother out of the train.